# Image wont attach to a text message even with a working URI

Tags: java, android, attachment

When I push the Share button, the SMS body goes in just fine, but I just can't get the image to show up. It just doesn't even look like there is any attachment.

I looked over all of my code and it looks fine, but I can't say I'm an expert on development yet so I'm probably looking over something.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

---

Getting the URI from the database (I know the URI is correct because an imageview displays correctly based on this same URI):

```
imageURI = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE)));
```

This is where I try to set the URI to the attachment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.action_shareWine) {
Intent intentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intentShare.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
        intentShare.putExtra("sms_body", "The sms body goes here";
//Attaching the image I want into the text:
        intentShare.putExtra(intentShare.EXTRA_STREAM, imageURI);
        if (intentShare.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intentShare);
        }
```

---

And it case it helps, this is how I'm getting the URI originally:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "jeremy.com.wineofmine.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: **S**MS don't exchange any attachment. **M**MS do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the intentShare code to this:

```
Intent intentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intentShare.putExtra(intentShare.EXTRA_STREAM, imageURI);
        intentShare.setType("image/*");
        intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The sms body goes here");
        if (intentShare.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intentShare);
        }
```

ModularSynth helped me realize that ACTION_SENDTO wouldn't work, since that is only text.

Another thing that might help someone is that when I changed to ti ACTION_SEND, it was only putting in the image at first, with no body. I fixed that also.

Instead of this line:

```
intentShare.putExtra("sms_body", "The sms body goes here";
```

Replace it with:

```
 intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The sms body goes here");
```

That will let you send both the image and the text in the MMS.

Answer (score 0):

Call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` to the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` before calling `startActivity()`. Right now, you are attaching the `Uri`, but the recipient has no rights to read the content identified by that `Uri`.

Comment: I added this line of code but it did not fix this issue. 'intentShare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);'